# What is the browser neutral replacement for HTMLFormElement's all method?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

I'm using an institutional (ie, any fix will have to be on my side) website that is IE specific, but I want to use it with Safari.  The website *mostly* works, but at one point I get the following error in my console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLFormElement> has no method 'all'
```

When I dig into the Javascript the error is coming from:

```
function fnFocus() {
        var frmCtl = document.frmAddEditAdultPosition ;
        if(frmCtl !=null) {
            var ctlFN = frmCtl.all("txtFirstName") ;
            ctlFN.focus() ;
        }
    }
```

Calls to the all method are scattered throughout the code.

My plan, is to use [proxypy](https://code.google.com/p/proxpy/) to fix the Javascript as it comes in.  I'm assuming that the all method is something IE specific, but I don't know what I should replace it with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`elements` collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.elements):

```
frmCtl.elements["txtFirstName"] // Might be another collection if there are duplicate fields of that name
```

or [`getElementsByName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName):

```
frmCtl.getElementsByName("txtFirstName") // Always a collection
```

or [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelector):

```
frmCtl.querySelector('[name="txtFirstName"]') // Gets the first match
```

or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll):

```
frmCtl.querySelectorAll('[name="txtFirstName"]') // Always a collection
```